# Is it possible for a view-based NSTableView to draw outside the row bounds?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I have an `NSTableView` with 2 columns. Each column contains a different `NSTableCellView` subclass and in some situations I'd like to achieve an overlapping effect, so for example the top of the view in column 1 row 1 could be positioned above the bottom of the previous column 0 row 0 view.

I understand that there's no point in setting the frame of the NSTableCellView subclass instance in `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row` since it will always be overridden, but it feels like the clipping could be happening at the row level as well as the cell level.

Is it possible to draw outside the cell/row bounds?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for *any* view to draw outside its bounds if you mess with the graphics context; it's just the entirely wrong thing to do in the much same way it's wrong to "scribble" all over memory not under your application's purview.

A safer (more respectful to the system's drawing state) approach would be to fudge it by drawing the background of each NSTableRowView yourself, but "offset" vertically within its own bounds so that row *n* draws row *n*-1's bottom for all rows except the first row. That is, on all but the first row, the "top edge" of the row view draws what looks like the bottom edge of the previous row view; the bottom edge is "cut off" in drawing. This way, you sacrifice the relatively minor convenience of flipping a switch to get view shadows for the finer control of how the rows are drawn.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. That's an interesting solution. What I didn't say was that I also need the ability to hide (with animation) the rows in second column so I'd rather keep cells only needing to draw their own content. I think I'm heading towards either 2 separate tableViews with synced scrolling (which would eliminate the overlap problem) or a completely custom subview approach along the lines of PxListView.

Comment: Then move the described drawing logic into the cell views instead of the row view. Two table views is ... well ... a bit Rube-Goldberg-esque. :-)